# Python cant import any module after upgrade

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, linux-mint

I recently installed Linux Mint and it came with Python 2.7.4. I installed Python 2.7.10 from source and now any module I import throws the error: "ImportError: No module named ". When I type in pip freeze, I definitely have the modules I am trying to import. Even if I try to import modules in the interactive python shell, it throws the same error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your `sys.path`. Do this in interactive python shell, `import sys` and then `print sys.path`. Add the output of that command to your question. The modules which you have installed using pip are stored in a `site-packages` directory, and it should be there in `sys.path`, for you to be able to import it.

Comment: Note: In Linux Mint, the installed modules go in `/usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages`. To confirm this, in shell type, `ls /usr/local/lib/python/dist-packages` and see the output, you should see the modules you had installed using `pip`. Now check `sys.path` again, and see if it has the path mentioned above or not.

Comment: did you install 2.7.10 along with 2.7.4 or did you replace it?